# Xcode iphone sdk - Searching in UITableView, different pattern matching

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios4, uisearchbar

I'm coding a UITableView with a UISearchBar to search between a list of cities (loaded in the uitableview)

Here is my code for searhing:

```
- (void) searchTableView {
NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;
NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *dictionary in listOfItems)
{
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Cities"];
    [searchArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
}

for (NSString *sTemp in searchArray)
{
    NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
        [copyListOfItems addObject:sTemp];
}

[searchArray release];
searchArray = nil;}
```

And with this everything works fine, but i need to do something a bit different. 
I need to search only between items that match pattern Word* and not * Word *.

For example if I search "roma", this need to match just with "Roma" or "Romania" and not with "Castelli di Roma".
Is that possible with this searchbar? How can i modify this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should check `if (titleResultsRange.length > 0 && titleResultsRange.location == 0)` instead of just `(titleResultsRange.length > 0)`